# ruby get next value on each loop

Tags: ruby, each

Can I get the next value in an each loop?

```
(1..5).each do |i|
    @store = i + (next value of i)
end
```

where the answer would be..

1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 = 29

And also can I get the next of the next value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
range = 1..5
store = 0

range.each_with_index do |value, i|
  next_value = range.to_a[i+1].nil? ? 0 : range.to_a[i+1]
  store += value + next_value
end    

p store # => 29
```

There may be better ways, but this works.

You can get the next of the next value like this:

```
range.to_a[i+2]
```

Comment: This code would break if range were changed, such as to `11..15`: it'd give 65 when it should give 119.

Comment: nice! thanks for your quick reply! On second thought, @AndrewGrimm was right.

Comment: @jovhenni19, I updated my answer so it works with AndrewGrimm's example too.

Answer (score 20):

From as early as [Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), the Enumerable module has had a method [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) that does almost exactly what you want:

> ## each_cons(n) { ... } → nil
> each_cons(n) → [an_enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerator.html)
>
> Iterates the given block for each array of consecutive <n> elements. If no block is given, returns an enumerator.
>
> e.g.:
>
> ```
> (1..10).each_cons(3) { |a| p a }
> # outputs below
> [1, 2, 3]
> [2, 3, 4]
> [3, 4, 5]
> [4, 5, 6]
> [5, 6, 7]
> [6, 7, 8]
> [7, 8, 9]
> [8, 9, 10]
> ```

The only problem is that it doesn't repeat the last element. But that's trivial to fix. Specifically, you want

```
store = 0
range = 1..5

range.each_cons(2) do |i, next_value_of_i|
    store += i + next_value_of_i
end
store += range.end

p store # => 29
```

But you could also do this:

```
range = 1..5

result = range.each_cons(2).reduce(:+).reduce(:+) + range.end

p result # => 29
```

Alternatively, you may find the following to be more readable:

```
result = range.end + range.each_cons(2)
                          .reduce(:+)
                          .reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach that wouldn't use indexes is Enumerable#zip:

```
range = 11..15
store = 0 # This is horrible imperative programming
range.zip(range.to_a[1..-1], range.to_a[2..-1]) do |x, y, z|
  # nil.to_i equals 0
  store += [x, y, z].map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
store
```